# getElementbyId is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have a simple piece of JavaScript that changes the color of a button, but I keep getting he error that getting the button is not a function, even though the same function (with the same capitalisation and case) works just a couple of lines above.

```
if (this.ButtonColor != "") {
      var button = document.getElementbyId('modal-close');
      button.style.backgroundColor = this.ButtonColor;
 }
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('modal-close');`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is `document.getElementById()`, not `document.getElementbyId()`

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a typo, the function you are looking for is `getElementById`.
**By** with a capital B instead of **by**.

[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is a reference to that method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this.ButtonColor did you try

```
var button = document.getElementById("modal-close");
button.style.backgroundColor = "the color you want rather than using "
```